Linearizing/Approximating Nonlinear Stochastic Differential Equations
I'm working with a multivariate stochastic differential equation (SDE) of the form
\begin{equation}
   \mathrm{d} \boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{x},t) \mathrm{d}t + 
   \boldsymbol{G}(\boldsymbol{x},t) \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{w} \ ,
\end{equation}
where $\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\boldsymbol{w} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is standard Brownian motion. I want to linearize the SDE about a nominal deterministic "trajectory," $\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}$, defined by the ODE
\begin{equation}
   \mathrm{d}\bar{\boldsymbol{x}} = \boldsymbol{f}(\bar{\boldsymbol{x}},t)\mathrm{d}t \ .
\end{equation}
Defining the error vector, $\delta \boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{x} - \bar{\boldsymbol{x}}$, one may write the error SDE as
\begin{equation}
   \mathrm{d}\delta \boldsymbol{x} = \big( \boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{x},t) - 
   \boldsymbol{f}(\bar{\boldsymbol{x}},t) \big) \mathrm{d}t + \boldsymbol{G} 
   (\boldsymbol{x},t) \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{w} \ .
\end{equation}
To the first order, the error SDE is expressed as
\begin{align}
   \mathrm{d}\delta x_i =& \left[ \frac{\partial f_i(\boldsymbol{x},t)}{\partial 
   \boldsymbol{x}} \Big|_{\boldsymbol{x} = \bar{\boldsymbol{x}}(t)} \right] \delta 
   \boldsymbol{x} \mathrm{d}t \\
&+ \left( \boldsymbol{g}_i(\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}(t),t) + \delta 
   \boldsymbol{x}^T \left[ \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{g}_i(\boldsymbol{x},t)}{\partial 
   \boldsymbol{x}^T} \Big|_{\boldsymbol{x} = \bar{\boldsymbol{x}}(t)} \right] \right) 
   \mathrm{d} \boldsymbol{w} \ ,
\end{align}
where the subscript $i$ indicates the $i$th row of the associated variable, i.e., $\boldsymbol{g}_i$ is the $i$th row of $\boldsymbol{G}$.
The resulting SDE appears to be a blend between a time-varying Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process and multivariate geometric Brownian motion. I was wondering if this SDE has a name/solution in the literature. More importantly, can I express the transition density, $p(\delta \boldsymbol{x}_k | \delta \boldsymbol{x}_{k-1})$, over a given increment $t_{k-1}$ to $t_k$ of the stochastic process, with a parameterizable probability density?

It helps to simplify notation in that last SDE, and to find out if it has a name or solution it does not matter how you motivated it. If it were not multidimensional it looks to me like the Linear SDE: General Case in the standard WP list. Your first task is to confirm that.
